# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION for Map location App

Tags: swift, core-location, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm very new to coding so please forgive me.  I'm trying to run a program on my Apple Watch that tells me my location coordinates, altitude, speed, and course.

Everything was working up to my `println(userlocationInfo)` line, but then I got an error at my `let row = table.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as! tableRowController`:

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

By the way, what exactly does that error message mean?  How can I solve an error message like this in the future by myself?

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var table: WKInterfaceTable!


    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var userLocationInfo = [String]()

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {


        let locationArray = locations as NSArray

        let location = locationArray.lastObject as! CLLocation

        userLocationInfo.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

        userLocationInfo.append("\(location.coordinate.latitude)")

        userLocationInfo.append("\(location.coordinate.longitude)")

        userLocationInfo.append("\(location.altitude)")

        userLocationInfo.append("\(location.speed)")

        userLocationInfo.append("\(location.course)")

        println(userLocationInfo)

        table.setNumberOfRows(userLocationInfo.count, withRowType: "tableRowController")

        for (index, value) in enumerate(userLocationInfo) {

            let row = table.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as! tableRowController

            row.tableRowLabel.setText(value)

        }


    }

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move your table function out of the `didUpdateLocations` delegate and call it after you have the location data. The `didUpdateLocations` will continue to run until you stop updating locations.